# Automate some actions in a browser (via Selenium?)

Tags: android, selenium, browser, uwp, webdriver

I need to automate some actions (testing ajax login on demand) in a browser.

I manage to obtain the desired behavior using selenium and chromedriver on my pc, but I need to make it work either in a UWP app or in an Android app (*and must run without a pc once deployed)...

Notes:

- UWP App

  - It's a web service that runs on Windows 10 IOT Core on a Raspberry 3b+ (ARM7)
  - Selenium seems to be incompatible to UWP apps... Maybe because of they are sandboxed and can't start new processes?
  - The app won't be published on windows store
  - I can add all needed capabilities
- Android

  - It's an app that remotly commands the UWP app
  - Selenium integration compiled but execution blocks on "webDriver.get(url)"; I did'nt find a way to make it work yet.
- I'm flexible concerning software/os/browser/libraries/etc to use.
- The UWP & Android Apps are kinda complexe (they have many file...)
- I don't know how to install a browser on the IOT Core (did'nt find an msix or appxbundle I could use)

Some ideas I had:
    - Deploying the ARM7 chromedriver with a portable ARM7 chromium with the app
    - Using dockers
    - Using raspbian & mono

The ideal solution would be simple and working on android (if possible)...

Any of you have an idea of how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I reproduced the desired behavior in Android using a WebView and javascript using the evaluateJavascript method.

It's a little tricky but perfect for my need.